# Use working sets by default in Eclipse RCP

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

How can I set programmatically an RCP to use working sets as top level elements in the Project Explorer by default instead of projects?

Comment: Use them where? Packages Explorer? Projects Explorer?

Comment: Project Explorer. Edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

The Packages View is `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart`.

The value of the top level elements mode is saved in a `IDialogSettings` object in the state location for the `org.eclipse.jdt.ui` plugin (so this is a `dialog_settings.xml` file in the `org.eclipse.jdt.ui` folder in the workspace `.metadata`).

The entry key value is `rootMode` in the `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart` section. A value of `2` sets working sets top level.

You would have to set this value **before** the packages view opens. Once the view is open there are no accessible APIs to change the value (everything is internal).

**Note:** all the above is defined in internal classes and is therefore not part of the Eclipse API and may be changed without notice.

Comment: Thank you for the directions. Now I can't find out where I should call the PackageExplorerPart. I tried it in my WorkbenchAdvisor, but `getFromActivePerspective()` always returns `null`. I thought this kind of thing should be part of the Eclipse API.

Answer (score 1):

For programmatic access, you can get the Project Explorer's ViewPart (which is of class `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.ProjectExplorer`) and call the `setRootMode` method.

Alternatively, you can set it via the setting `org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.workingSets.showTopLevelWorkingSets`

Comment: Ok, I got the ProjectExplorer from the WorkbenchPage, but calling `setRootMode` has no effect. Do I need to do anything besides calling this method with `ProjectExplorer.WORKING_SETS`?

Comment: It could probably be because WorkingSetActionProvider.restoreState() overrode what you did.